# Should I close a question because the answer is "typo"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

[What is the grammar of “the blur the protect the identity”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/71795/11458)

After the problem has been identified as "typo", I realize that this should be close because, well, typo is not a proper English grammar. Should I close this question?

And if yes, which flag to use?

Comment: BTW the question in question is closed right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen previous questions based on typos getting closed. [Here's the proof](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Aell.stackexchange.com+based+on+a+typo&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&oq=site%3Aell.stackexchange.com+based+on+a+typo&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.13155j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

I'm personally *for* closing them, since

- they won't benefit anyone else.
- the answer would shift from being based on expertise in 
  linguistics/terminology/whatever to being based on . . . whatever.
- they're not about English, any more than [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39608/effect-of-temperature-on-ph-of-water) is.

If I sit and think more thoroughly, I'll come up with more reasons, but you get the idea.

Comment: Agree for the reasons mentioned, especially for random typo by random people. Even there's a dedicated off-topic reason for "[simple typographical error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" on  [so], a programming Q&A.